# Why is Trailing take profit a non existent functionality from brokers

Tags: trading, brokerage, day-trading, online-brokerage, online-trading

If i understand  this correct a trailing stop loss line can be put between the current market price and what you bought  it for  and your taking an L  on the trade ...etc...

but why is the opposite practically  non existent  on brokers
eg : you buy long and your making money £50+ in profit ...but you are unsure whether its gonna go up more  or not so instead of closing then and there you say ok ...im fine with making £30 profit so you place a trailing  take profit ...and then the market price falls below that line and you close with £30 profit...instead of having to constantly  look at your portfolio to check if your still making a profit.

ps you can only put take profit at above what the current market price is at any given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand stop orders, if I understand your question right.

`Stop Loss` order is "I bought for $20, if it goes below $18 sell".  That's a "avoid losing too much money" order.  It can be set at a point below, or above, the original sale point; if the stock is now $30 you could set it at $27, no problem.

`Trailing Stop` order is "The current market price is $30, if it loses more than 10%, sell, and adjust this order up if the stock moves up."  It locks in profits on a stock, basically.  It adjusts with that current market price; it's used to do what you say in the question, attempts to lock in profits on a profitable long position that is relatively constantly growing.

Both can do what you're describing to some extent; the difference is in whether it automatically adjusts up or not.  Don't be confused by the word "loss" here; it's a loss *relative to the current moment*, not a loss relative to your original purchase price.

If that's not what you're asking for, then please clarify the question.  [This Investopedia page](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/stocks/09/use-stop-loss.asp#:%7E:text=A%20stop%2Dloss%20order%20is%20an%20order%20placed%20with%20a,limit%20your%20loss%20to%2010%25.) explains limit sell orders.

Comment: You known sometimes i over think stuff and don't realise  the answer  is right under my nose.

Comment: i just lost around €100 euros and alot of sleep  because of this.

Comment: A stop order only "locks in profits on a stock" if there is an orderly retracement in price.  If the stock gaps down, the fill could be anywhere.  Only a put option locks in a hard stop, assuming the stock has options.

Comment: @BobBaerker Right, it doesn't truly "lock it in", I'm being loose with the words here.  Added "Attempts to" to make that clear.